# SYMFONY FormTypeCollection with various fields

Tags: forms, symfony

In my project I would like to be able to add a Collection on a Form. I thought about the FormTypeCollection. But the thing is, I need something like that:
A "New" button, at the end of the form and everytime you click on the new, a "mini-form" is added and you have the three input to fill: "name,text,link". I would like it to be stored in the database as artists = [name,text,link] for example. I have no idea how to do that. i don't want to add an Entity Artist because I just need this for display and I don't need it to be stored as an Entity on the database.
My code right now is like that:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->with('Contenu')
            ->add('published', CheckboxType::class, ['required' => false, 'label' => 'Publier'])
            ->add('title', TextType::class, ['required' => true, 'label' => 'Titre'])
            ->add('marketingEtiquette', TextType::class, ['required' => false, 'label' => 'Etiquette Marketing'])
            ->add('textLink', TextType::class, ['required' => true, 'label' => 'Texte du lien'])
            ->add('shoppingLink', TextType::class, ['required' => true, 'label' => 'Lien'])
            ->add('media', ElFinderType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Photo',
                'instance' => 'form',
                'enable' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')
                )
            )
            ->add('position',ChoiceType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Position dans la page',
                'choices' => array(
                    'Bloc Artistes' => 'artists',
                    'Bloc haut de page' => 'top',
                    'Bloc bas de page' => 'bottom'
                )
            ))
            ->add('artists',CollectionType::class,array(
                'label' => 'Les artistes',
                'allow_add' => true,
            ))
            ->end();
    }
```

I don't know how to add 3 fields to the field artists and generate them on the add button click. i don't even know if it's possible actually. I also don't know what should be the type 'artists' in the database.

EDIT:
I would have like to do something similar to that, so I don't need to create an Entity nor a FormType:

```
->add('artists',CollectionType::class,array(
                'entry_type' => TextType::class ,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'artistName' => TextType::class,
                    'artistText' => TextType::class,
                    'artistLink' => TextType::class,
                ],
                'label' => 'Les artistes',
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'delete_empty' => true,
                'by_reference' => false
            ))
```

But it's not working so I guess I can't. Error:

```
The current field `artists` is not linked to an admin. Please create one for the target entity : ``
```

EDIT 2:
I created my ArtistFormType:

```
class ArtistFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('artistName', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Nom de l\'artiste'
            ))
            ->add('artistText', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Texte sous l\'artiste'
            ))
            ->add('artistLink', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Lien vers l\'artiste'
            ))
            ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
           'data_class' => null,
       ]);
    }
}
```

I called it like that:

```
->add('artists',CollectionType::class,array(
                'entry_type' => ArtistFormType::class,
                'label' => 'Les artistes',
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'delete_empty' => true,
                'by_reference' => false
            ))
```

But I get the same error:

```
The current field `artists` is not linked to an admin. Please create one for the target entity : ``
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : This solution is limited to Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType, it might be different with the one from Sonata Admin.

You can find some information on this in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html).

The "easiest" way to do that, is to create another form (ArtistFormType for example) with the fields you wish to add.
Then in your parent form you add the CollectionType :

```
$formMapper
        // ...
        ->add('artists', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => ArtistFormType::class,
            'label' => 'Artists',
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'delete_empty' => true,
            'by_reference' => false
        ])
    ;
```

Then if you already have some artists in your entity it will render the ArtistFormType once for each artist.

If you want to add new artists it is a bit trickier and requires some Javascript.

First, render the collection inside an `<ul></ul>` tag :

```
<ul class="artists">
    {{ form_row(form.artists) }}
</ul>
```

Following this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/847Kf/4/) :
Find the collection and add an "add artist" button to it

```
<script>
var $addArtistLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_artist_link">Add an artist</a>');
var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addArtistLink);

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Get the ul that holds the collection of artists
    var $collectionHolder = $('ul.artists');

    // add the "add a tag" anchor and li to the tags ul
    $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);
    
    // ...
}
</script>
```

Add the "click" event with some dom manipulations to add new artists :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // ...
    
    // count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
    // index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
    $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

    $addArtistLink.on('click', function(e) {
        // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
        e.preventDefault();
    
        // add a new artist form
        addArtistForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
    });


});

function addArtistForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
    // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
    var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');

    // get the new index
    var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');

    // Replace '$$name$$' in the prototype's HTML to
    // instead be a number based on how many items we have
    var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

    // increase the index with one for the next item
    $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

    // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add an artist" link li
    var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);

    // also add a remove button
    $newFormLi.append('<a href="#" class="remove-artist">x</a>');

    $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);

    // handle the removal
    $('.remove-artist').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        $(this).parent().remove();
    
        return false;
   });
```

}

Then it should work fine. Of course some changes might be done to fit your project (field names, add the remove button on existing artists, ...).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I'm trying it, but I have to create an Artist Entity to do that? The thing is, I'd like to not create an Artist Entity. Is this possible? Or do I have to create an Entity?

Comment: I think it will be easier (and better) to create an Artist entity with a ManyToOne relation to the Entity of the main Form.
If you really don't want to create this Entity, you can specify "'data_class' => null" in your ArtistFormType and then it will normalize the data as an array instead of an Entity.

Comment: Okay because I thought I could do something like I did in my edit, it is not possible then?

Comment: It won't work this way. I think you will at least have to create the ArtistFormType. Also, the "entry_options" is used to set the options of the FormType in the "entry_type" and not fields like you have done in your edit.

Comment: Okay, I did it but not working, I edited my question ^^

Comment: Does your entity have an "artists" property ? If not, try to add it or set "'mapped' => false" in the field 'artists' if you don't need to read from/write to database. Otherwise, there may be some difference between CollectionType from Symfony and from Sonata Admin (I assume you are using Sonata here) that force you to have an admin to deal with the 'artists'. I don't have a solution for the latter though (other than creating the Artist entity and admin).

Comment: Yes I do have a field artists, defined like that   `/**
     * @var
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="home_element_artists", type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $artists;` And yes, I do use Sonata. Where should i set `mapped => false`?

Comment: Which CollectionType are you using (Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type or Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type) ? You can set it inside the CollectionType after "'by_reference' => false" for example, but if you do no value will be submitted for this field so you will need to set it manually.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! I was actually using the wrong CollectionType, I changed it to `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type` and the error disappeared. I will try the rest of your answer now, thanks again

Comment: You are welcome, I hope it works fine. I edited my answer to avoid this confusion.